# Enabling the empty base class optimization globally in a C++ project on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, clang, c++20

MSVC seems to disable empty base class optimization (EBO/EBCO) when using multiple inheritance. Sadly, this means that other compilers targetting windows have to also disable EBO in such scenarios. Now, MSVC provides `__declspec(empty_bases)` for re-enabling it, but now you have to put this attribute in every class that relies EBO.

Is there a way to disable this behavior globally? That is, are there any compiler flags that will re-enable EBO for a project?

(I'm mainly interested in clang with the GNU command line).

Comment: As there is no C++ ABI compatibility between different compilers why is this a problem ?

Comment: It appears Clang attempts to be abi-compatible when targetting Windows. I tested using __declspec(empty_bases) with Clang and it fixed the problem. However I want a solution that doesn't involve this attribute.

Comment: What I mean is all the rest of the potentially ABI breaking compiler differences (not just empty bases) makes the question unclear to me - why just focus on this one issue ?

Comment: Oh, my problem specifically is that I want to use the CRTP and that I'm also relying on the memory layout of those types being consistent with the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to disable this behavior globally?

That would break ABI compatibility with every type declared by any C++ code on your platform. Including code from your standard library or any pre-compiled library you link to, as well as any DLLs and the like. So... no, there is no way to do that.

Platform ABIs, even when they are wrong, are not *optional*. If you want to have a type that doesn't follow platform ABI rules, that type's declaration has to have something in it to distinguish itself from those which do follow the platform's ABI rules.

Comment: That's quite a shame, but it makes sense. Thank you!